# Trying to store numbers in an array and display them by reading from a file

Tags: c

I am trying to read the numbers only from a file named Store-1.txt. This file contains the following: "coffee 3Mugs -3Soap 10"
I am using the `fscanf()` function instead of `getc()`.
My code does not compile. where am I going wrong. PS: I am new to C. please be patient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int i,j;


    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("C:/Users/PSN/Desktop/Store-1.txt","r");
    if(fp>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i])
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[j]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    system("PAUSE");  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have something that doesn't compile, please also post the compilation errors.

Comment: If you made the effort to format/indent your code properly, it would be obvious even for you where you are missing a curly brace, a semicolon, a pair of quotes, etc.

Comment: Your code is not compiling because you're missing a semi-colon on your `fscanf()` call.

Comment: @WhozCraig So you edited the code and now it has no errors, so the question is not meaningful anymore... Please don't fix the syntax error, only the formatting.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, my bad. throwing it back in there.

Comment: For writing nice C code, follow [the Kernel Coding Style.](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle)

Comment: ok..the ; was missing. but the code does not give me the result . it shows some garbage value. last night Omkant had written a code, but i want to use fscanf.(I want to use my code.!).:-( Is my logic wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your input file, 'store-1.txt', looks like this:

```
coffee 3
Mugs -3
Soap 10
```

then try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int i;  

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("store-1.txt","r");

    if(fp>0) {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            fscanf(fp,"%*s %d", &a[i]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

should get you heading in the right direction...

note `%*s` tells fscanf there is a string but to ignore it

an alternative for the intended input:

```
coffee 3Mugs -3Soap 10
```

could be:

```
int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int i,j;  

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("store-1.txt","r");

    fscanf(fp, "%*s%d%*s%d%*s%d", word, &a[0], word, &a[1], word, &a[2]);

    /* if(fp>0) { */
    /*     for(i=0;i<3;i++) { */
    /*         fscanf(fp,"%s %d",word, &a[i]); */
    /*     } */
    /* } */
    for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[j]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

this would work on your input file, but prob not as extensible as you would want it?

Comment: ok, but i need to specify the full path right? 
And my Store-1.txt looks like..."coffee 3Mugs -3Soap 10" . I mean there is no newline. Everything on 1 line. I havent run your code but why do i need to incluse a %s.? Wont %d ignore everything except int ??

Comment: ok - i thought maybe you just hadn't added the newlines in your OP. yes you can add the full path - i just ran the exe in the same dir as th input file so didn't need a full path. you'd have to do something a bit smarter i think if you want to pull out no.s from a single line without having whitespace between them and the words.

Comment: a regexp would be the 1st thing that springs to my mind but to be honest I'd recommend just using newlines 1st and working on your basic C skills

Comment: yes, your code works, so we need to dump the strings by using %s and then save the numbers %d . But I had understood scanf works like-It searches to through the string and as soon as it matches a %d, it stores it. I am heart-broken that i could not get the code to run myself. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: ya. saw it. But your earlier code works fine. i have checked it..:-)

Comment: don't stress it - just keep practicing

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing a semi-colon.

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i])
```

Should be:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]);
```

---

If you want to read only the numbers in the second column of your file, you can read the first column and just ignore it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int i,j;
    char str[256];

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("C:/Users/PSN/Desktop/Store-1.txt","r");
    if(fp>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", str); // read the first column & ignore
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i])
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[j]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    system("PAUSE");  
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I changed your loop from 4 to 3 as you have only 3 lines. Better way would be to not hardcode the line read till the end of the file. But that depends on the format of your input file and how many values you want to read etc.

Comment: yup..corrected that. now the code runs but its not doing wat it is supposed to do..:-(

Comment: @PSN When you `%d` in the fscanf, it expect an int. But your file has string `coffee`. I'll update my answer with the code.

Comment: @PSN You need to include more information in general if you need help. Try and give the code, correctly formatted, the error from the compiler if it won't compile or what it's *doing* and what it *should* be doing if it's not functioning corretly.

Comment: @joe...sorry for not giving the compilation error. I will remember to do so from next time..:-)
Hiett's answer works, but I am sad i could not get the code running by myself..:-(

Comment: @PSN I am not entirely clear what you want to do. You just want to print only the integers Or you want to read everything & print? or something else?

Comment: i need just to save the integers only in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[20];   
    int i,j;  

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("C:/Users/PSN/Desktop/Store-1.txt","r");
    if(fp>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]); // <You missed the ; here
        }
    }

    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[j]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    system("PAUSE");  
    return 0;
}
```

Which is coincidentally a good example of indenting... :-)